# No API Key defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, flickr, figaro-ruby

Hi I am new to rails and I am building a flickr feed app that lets a user display photos from a flickr feed when they enter their id, however I am getting this error when I go to the `localhost:3000`:

```
Flickr::FlickrAppNotConfigured in StaticPagesController#index
No API key defined!
```

```yaml
# application.yml

flickr_key: "Not showing this"
flickr_secret: "Not showing this either"
```

`static_pages_controller.rb`:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  require 'flickr'

  def index
    flickr = Flickr.new
    unless params[:user_id].blank?
      @photos = flickr.photos.search(user_id: params[:user_id])
    else
      @photos = flickr.photos.getRecent
    end
  end
end
```

`Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

gem "figaro"
gem 'flickr', '~> 2.1'
# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

`Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
    activerecord (7.0.4)
      activemodel (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
    activestorage (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (7.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    addressable (2.8.1)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.15.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capybara (3.38.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    crass (1.0.6)
    debug (1.7.0)
      irb (>= 1.5.0)
      reline (>= 0.3.1)
    erubi (1.11.0)
    figaro (1.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14.0, < 2)
    flickr (2.1.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.12.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    importmap-rails (1.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    io-console (0.5.11)
    irb (1.5.1)
      reline (>= 0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    loofah (2.19.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.8.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.16.3)
    msgpack (1.6.0)
    net-imap (0.3.1)
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.1.3)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.9-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    public_suffix (5.0.0)
    puma (5.6.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.4)
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (7.0.4)
      actioncable (= 7.0.4)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.4)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      actiontext (= 7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activemodel (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.4)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.5)
    rake (13.0.6)
    regexp_parser (2.6.1)
    reline (0.3.1)
      io-console (~> 0.5)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (4.7.1)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sprockets (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.5.4-x86_64-linux)
    stimulus-rails (1.2.1)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    thor (1.2.1)
    timeout (0.3.0)
    turbo-rails (1.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activejob (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
    websocket (1.2.9)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.6)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap
  capybara
  debug
  figaro
  flickr (~> 2.1)
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails (~> 7.0.4)
  selenium-webdriver
  sprockets-rails
  sqlite3 (~> 1.4)
  stimulus-rails
  turbo-rails
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webdrivers

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.14
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should properly pass the credentials to client instance. As per [gem docs](https://github.com/cyclotron3k/flickr#getting-started), you have 2 ways:

```
# The credentials can be provided as parameters:
flickr = Flickr.new "YOUR API KEY", "YOUR SHARED SECRET"

# Alternatively, if the API key and Shared Secret are not provided, Flickr will attempt to read them from environment variables:
# ENV['FLICKR_API_KEY']
# ENV['FLICKR_SHARED_SECRET']
flickr = Flickr.new

# Flickr will raise an error if either parameter is not explicitly provided, or available via environment variables.
```

So be sure, if you're following the ENV approach (as it seems, since you are using `figaro` too), the ENV vars have the proper nanimg: `FLICKR_API_KEY` and `FLICKR_SHARED_SECRET` (instead of `FLICKR_KEY` and `FLICKR_SECRET`).

Comment: Thanks It works now, I was so frustrated all day, and feel so relieved now, you are a life saver!